# Bleachbit command not clearing trash

Tags: bleachbit

The output of `sudo bleachbit --clean system.trash` is:

```
Disk space recovered: 0
Files deleted: 0
```

The rubbish bin does contain items, and are still visible after running the command. Am I using the wrong syntax?

Comment: You run it as root and it cleans only root's trash. Why don't you clear the user's trash a more conventional way?

Comment: It's part of a larger script. Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, sudo can change the user directory (~) to refer to the root user, so BleachBit will clean root's trash (under `/root`) instead of your standard account's trash (under /home/`username`). If you run BleachBit with sudo in GUI mode, it will warn you about this.

So, take off `sudo` to clean the normal user's trash.

See also the [FAQ: On Linux do I need to run BleachBit both as a normal user and as an administrator?](https://docs.bleachbit.org/doc/frequently-asked-questions.html)